# Taking Substring from a delimited string based on condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, substring, delimiter

I have a delimited

```
string ";2;5;2;5;04/02/2014;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2015;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2016;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2017;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2018;3;100.000000;"
```

The format for the data is as follows:

```
1st character:  Delimiter used within this format field
Number of dimensions 
Delimiter
Number of rows
Delimiter
Number of columns
Delimiter
...Data Elements…
Delimiter
```

I want to extract this data inside a query or a function to get the Data Elements in a table format like

```
ScheduleDate    ScheduleValue
04/02/2015  100.000000
04/02/2016  100.000000
04/02/2017  100.000000
04/02/2018  100.000000
04/02/2016  34428.9700
04/02/2017  34428.9700
04/02/2018  34428.9700
04/02/2019  34428.9700
```

Also here `“5”` indicates a date, `“04/02/2015”` is the actual date, `“3”` indicates a price and `“100.00000”` is the actual price.
Similarly other indicators are like :

```
       1 Character
       2 Numeric
       3 Price  
       4 Security
       5 Date    
       6 Time    
       7 Date or time      
       8 Bulk
       9 Month/Year
```

I need to configure in that function or query to accommodate this as well.
I would be highly obliged if some one can help.

Comment: I have tried segregating the data using split function, but I need to come up with a configurable table valued function which would take count of all these parameter to give me the output. Any suggestion how to go about a optimised approach will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no split function in SQL server; have you written it yourself or are you using .NET ?

Comment: I have written it in SQL Server.

Comment: ok, so your function has done the first part of the lexical analysis and have the tokens. The next part of the parsing could transform part of those tokens in a table definition and the rest into data to be inserted into the table. You can do this by generating dynamical sql statements.

Comment: if you feel comfortable with XML, you can convert the string into XML and then extract the data via Xpath/Xquery

Comment: I want to get rid of the first three parameters for the time being and then parse the rest of the string, code for which already in place. So i want the ";2;5;2;5;04/02/2014;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2015;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2016;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2017;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2018;3;100.000000;" to be "5;04/02/2014;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2015;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2016;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2017;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2018;3;100.000000;" . How to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of the first three parameters one of the things you can do this:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(max)
SET @string=';2;5;2;5;04/02/2014;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2015;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2016;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2017;3;100.000000;5;04/02/2018;3;100.000000;'
DECLARE @newstring VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @newstring=CAST((SELECT CAST('<Node>'+REPLACE(@string,';',';</Node><Node>')+'</Node>' AS XML).query('//Node[position()>4]/text()') ) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
SELECT @newstring
```

so this will basically leaves you data type and data, which you can parse with the existing code you mentioned